# Spark - Convert Tuples to Tab Seperated String

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a function that takes an RDD of tuples and converts each tuple to a tab separated string.  I want the function to be able to handle Tuples of any size.

If I already have this RDD created, I can get the desired output using:

```
rdd.map(line => (0 to (line.productArity-1)).map(line.productElement(_)).toList.mkString("\t"))
```

How can I convert this piece of code to work as a function that takes an RDD of tuples, or is there a good library that already does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def toTab[T <: Product](rdd:RDD[T]) = rdd.map(_.productIterator.mkString("\t"))
```